# PayPal - Bill Me Later as standalone option on Magento checkout page. Is it possible?

Tags: checkout, paypal, paylater

My main question is: Can we have PayPal – Bill Me Later as standalone payment option on Magento checkout page?

I spent 2 months playing around with the payment method called “Bill Me Later”.
After Magento released this information: http://www.magentocommerce.com/paypal/billmelater
some Magento shop owners were fooled, that we have “Bill Me Later” as standalone payment option. Of course this is not true, because Mangeto just said to the world, that everybody can put PayPal – Bill Me Later banners on their shops.

To get PayPal – Bill Me Later in Magento we have to activate PayPal  Payments Advanced from Magento admin. Also to apply some settings in  https://manager.paypal.com . After doing all needed actions I ended up with hosted iframe which contains checkout options. This iframe appear after I complete all checkout steps and I press the “place order” button. The checkout options are:

- checkout with PayPal
- checkout with PayPal – Bill Me Later
- Pay with credit or debit card

[image]

Do you know if PayPal – Bill Me Later can work in different way and we can have  PayPal – Bill Me Later as standalone payment option / method or even if it's possible to place the PayPal advance iframe in the payment options block before the “place order” button is pressed.

**So far I checked how the PayPal  API works and found, that to get the iframe we have to pass the order id to PayPal and some other parameters. That makes me think, that it's impossible to have the iframe before we have an order, but may be somebody from the community faced the same problem and knows, how this can be achieved.**

Comment: Just a bad hack, but you could push the iframe so high, that only the pay later button is visible.

Comment: This sounds nice, but the next problem, that should be solved is the fact, that I have to do a simulate click on the "BillMeLater" button. I am not totally sure, that this is possible to happen in iframe, because there are limitation with the JS actions in iframe environment.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. but I'm no JS expert

Comment: Usually it's not possible ... as I know, PayPay sends headers, that limit us:  X-FRAME-OPTIONS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464173/embed-paypal-in-an-iframe ... also for reference: The X-Frame-Options response header - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. As **ceckoslab** [noted](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2996/paypal-bill-me-later-as-standalone-option-on-magento-checkout-page-is-it-poss#comment-4117), iframe manipulation options are strenuously limited by PayPal.

The only potential option would be a standalone integration to BillMeLater, but no such API endpoint exists with that service; it must be accessed via PayPal's Web interface.